# What is the best place to declare the connection of my socket and my spot in the background?

Tags: c#, sockets, xaml, uwp

I develop an HMI under the UWP, it needs a connection to a server and a background task to monitor whether messages are received.

At the launch of the HMI, an extended splash screen is appearing with a progress ring. To unblock the startup, you have to receive  "launch_ok " from the server then we have access to the main page which allows to manage calls.

Currently I declare everything in my file: ExtendedSplash.xaml.cs

I declare my new socket with these settings, I run it and then I run my background activity.

I have also some errors : "Exception levée : 'System.NullReferenceException'"

ExtendedSplash.xaml.cs (Extract):

```
namespace PhoneCenter
{
partial class ExtendedSplash : Page
   {
    // SOCKET CONFIGURATION
    private const string socketId = "SampleSocket"; 
        private StreamSocket socket = null;
        private IBackgroundTaskRegistration task = null;
    private const string port = "40404";        
    private const string adress = "172.16.161.80"; 
}
public ExtendedSplash(SplashScreen splashscreen, bool loadState)
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window.Current.SizeChanged += new WindowSizeChangedEventHandler(ExtendedSplash_OnResize);
            splash = splashscreen;
    Debug.WriteLine("Création de la tâche d'arrière plan");
            StartBackgroundTask();
        Debug.WriteLine("Connexion Socket ...");
        StartConnexionServeurLTO();

            if (splash != null)
            {
            splash.Dismissed += new TypedEventHandler<SplashScreen, object>(DismissedEventHandler);
            splashImageRect = splash.ImageLocation;
            PositionImage();
            PositionRing();
            PositionTextBlock();
            }
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        RestoreState(loadState);
    }
// CONNEXION SOCKET
    private async void StartConnexionServeurLTO()
    {
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["hostname"] = adress;
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["port"] = port;

        try
        {
            SocketActivityInformation socketInformation;
            if (!SocketActivityInformation.AllSockets.TryGetValue(socketId, out socketInformation))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Boucle");
                socket = new StreamSocket();
                socket.EnableTransferOwnership(task.TaskId, SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction.Wake);
                var targetServer = new HostName(adress);
                await socket.ConnectAsync(targetServer, port);
                DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
                reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                var read = reader.LoadAsync(250);
                read.Completed += (info, status) =>
                {

                };
                await socket.CancelIOAsync();
                socket.TransferOwnership(socketId);
                socket = null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Echec dans la connexion au serveur");
        }
    }
// LANCEMENT TÂCHE EN ARRIERE PLAN
    private void StartBackgroundTask()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var current in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (current.Value.Name == "PhonieMarthaBackground")
                {
                    task = current.Value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (task == null)
            {
                var socketTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
                socketTaskBuilder.Name = "PhonieMarthaBackground";
                socketTaskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = "PhonieMarthaBackground.SocketActivityTask";
                var trigger = new SocketActivityTrigger();
                socketTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
                task = socketTaskBuilder.Register();
            }

            SocketActivityInformation socketInformation;
            if (SocketActivityInformation.AllSockets.TryGetValue(socketId, out socketInformation))
            {
                socket = socketInformation.StreamSocket;
                socket.TransferOwnership(socketId);
                socket = null;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Tâche d'arrière plan démarrée");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Wouldn't it be simpler to perform these actions in the App.xaml.cs file when launching OnLaunched? Could we call a function at the end of OnLaunched?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: I don't know ... It's appear on the Visual Debugger but it does not go into the try for the socket but the catch

Comment: You will need to set up a breakpoint and see how it runs line-by-line.

Comment: socket.TransferOwnership(socketId) it's this line

Comment: There are two such lines. Which one is throwing it?

Comment: In StartConnexionServeurLTO()

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that in the if you are checking whether the value was not found:

```
if (!SocketActivityInformation.AllSockets.TryGetValue(socketId, out socketInformation))
{
    // Your code
}
```

If this value is `false`, then a value for `socketId` was not found, therefore `socketInformation` (which was not initialized) will get the default value, which is `null`. This is the reason of the problem. You should change your if to enter to the code block if the value was found instead:

```
if (!SocketActivityInformation.AllSockets.TryGetValue(socketId, out socketInformation))
{
    // Your code
}
```